# How to apply flask_limiter to a route based on its variable based url?

Tags: flask, flask-limiter

I have a route where the final part is variable.

```py
api.add_resource(AsyncStatus, "generate/status/<string:id>")
```

In this route, I have applied a flask_limiter

```py
class AsyncStatus(Resource):
    decorators = [limiter.limit("1/minute")]
    def get(self, id = ''):
```

However, this limiter applies for the whole route. Want to apply the limiter to each `id` individually. So that the same IP can grab the `id` 1, `id` 2 and `id` 3 within the same minute, but cannot grab `id` 1, 3 times in the same minute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. I need to create a function and pick the path from the request

```py
from flask import request

def get_request_id():
    return(request.path)

class AsyncStatus(Resource):
    decorators = [limiter.limit("1/minute", key_func = get_request_id)]
    def get(self, id = ''):
```